# Gridview inserting

Tags: c#

Hi friends. So far as my previous post for gridview inserting without datasource, databind, dataset, or datatable I have used this coding still i am getting an error:

### design.aspx:

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeFile="Grid.aspx.cs" Inherits="Grid" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head id="Head1" runat="server">
  <title>Untitled Page</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    .style1
    {
      width: 97px;
    }
  </style>
</head>
<body>
  <form id="form1" runat="server" autocomplete="on">
  <div>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td class="style1">
          <asp:Label ID="empname" runat="server" Text="Emp Name"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtname" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="style1">
          <asp:Label ID="lblDesignation" runat="server" Text="Designation"></asp:Label>
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:TextBox ID="txtDesignation" runat="server"></asp:TextBox>
        </td>
        <td>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td class="style1">
        </td>
        <td>
          <asp:Button ID="btnadd" runat="server" Text="Add" OnClick="btnadd_Click" Style="height: 26px" />
          &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td>
          &nbsp;
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
    <table style="width: 100%;">
      <tr>
        <td>
        </td>
        <td>
          <div>
            <asp:GridView ID="grvname" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="False">
              <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Emp Name"></asp:TemplateField>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Designation"></asp:TemplateField>
              </Columns>
            </asp:GridView>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

### codebehind file:

```
using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Configuration;
using System.Data;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.Security;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.HtmlControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls.WebParts;
using System.Xml.Linq;

public partial class Grid : System.Web.UI.Page
{

  protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {

  }

  protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
  {
    GridViewRow row = new GridViewRow(-1, -1, DataControlRowType.DataRow, DataControlRowState.Normal);

    //Add the two Columns    
    row.Cells.AddRange(CreateCells());

    //get a reference to the table that holds this row
    //Table tbl = (e.Row.Parent as Table);
    Table tbl = (grvname.Rows[grvname.Rows.Count + 1].Parent as Table);------->getting error here 

    //Add the row at the end of the list, but before the footer.
    tbl.Rows.AddAt(grvname.Rows.Count + 1, row);

    //Add the row at the end of the list, but before the footer.
    //tbl.Rows.AddAt(grvname.Rows.Count + 1, row);
  }

  private TableCell[] CreateCells()
  {
    TableCell[] cells = new TableCell[2];
    TableCell cell;
    Label lbl;


    //The order item column
    cell = new TableCell();
    lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Text = txtname.Text;
    cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
    cells[0] = cell;

    //The price column
    cell = new TableCell();
    lbl = new Label();
    lbl.Font.Bold = true;
    lbl.Text = txtDesignation.Text;
    cell.HorizontalAlign = HorizontalAlign.Right;
    cell.Controls.Add(lbl);
    cells[1] = cell;
    return cells;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have used datatable for it. First insert data into the table. And assign it to the gridview.

http://www.aspnettutorials.com/tutorials/controls/data-table-csharp.aspx